# Merging two tables in Powerquery using both a case clause and a where function (should I use something else?

Tags: sql, if-statement, case, powerquery, where-in

I am trying to merge two tables in Powerquery. One is from a database, the other is from another source and has a set list of part numbers (pano20). Each part number has a source of supply (sos1) and some part numbers have two or more sources of supply each with differing unit costs (uncs). For example, part number 123 has a source of supply of both 000 and 530, but its unit cost under 000 is $1.50 and under 530 it is $2.50. There are 3 part numbers in my non-database table that I need to come from sos1 530 and the rest need to come from sos1 000. I am unsure which SQL to use, but I have used the one below. Obviously it is not working but I wanted to see if anyone had an idea of how I could do this.

```
use LIBCOM500

select sos1, uncs, ds18,
       case pano20
       when pano20 in ('ca2','oa1','oa1p') then sos1 = '530'
       else sos1 = '000'
from pcpprms0
```

Below is the desired output after merging the two tables.

```
Table 1 - excel table
|Part Number|Qty Needed|
|:---------:|---------:|
|    123    |     1    |
|    222    |     3    |

Table 2 - coming from database
|Part Number|SOS1|uncs|
|:---------:|:--:|---:|
|    123    |000 |1.50|
|    123    |530 |2.50|    
|    222    |000 |3.00|

Table 3 - Output from merging table 1 and 2 by part number
|Part Number|SOS1|uncs|Qty Needed|
|:---------:|:--:|:--:|---------:|
|    123    |530 |2.50|    1     |
|    222    |000 |3.00|    3     |
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the proper and common format of a case expression. You have too much in the expression and you didn't END it.

```
select sos1, uncs, ds18,
case 
 when pano20 in ('ca2','oa1','oa1p') then '530'
 else '000'
end sos1b
from pcpprms0
```

Comment: The SOS1 is coming from a database. For example, some part numbers have two SOS1 values depending on which store it is coming from. The price differs from store to store. My problem is for parts equaling ca2, oa1, and oa1p, I need the prices from store 530, and for the rest of the parts I need the prices from store 000.

Comment: That was not explained in the original question. Provide sample data and desired output. We have no idea if you are dealing with one or more tables now with this added detail.

Comment: I apologize, this is my first question. There is one table from the database that I will be merging with a table by part number. I didn't add this to my question because I am doing the merge through power query.

Comment: So do you have two price columns? One for store 530 and another from store 000?

Comment: No, they are both included in the SOS1 column. So for example, say a part number has two prices at two different sources, it will show duplicates for that part number with two different prices in the dataset.

Comment: And both would be in the SOS1 column

Comment: for example, if I wanted all values to have a 000 sos1 my query would be select pano20, uncs, ds18, sos1 from pcpprms0 where sos1 = '000' but in this case I have 3 part numbers that I need to pull the price from 530 instead of 000. The rest need to come from 000.

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output in your question.

Comment: Added example tables to the question, does this explain it? @isolated

Answer (score 0):

Try this query may be it will help

```
select case when pano20 in ('ca2','oa1','oa1p') then '530' else '000'
end as sos1,uncs, ds18 from pcpprms0
```

Comment: So this "sort of" worked. It came out not null for the uncs values but the price output does not match what is in our system for 530

Comment: Which column for price value ? Right now what output this query ? What is your expected result ?

Comment: As per your table 2 , part number 123 belong to two sos number 000, 530.  Then how you need to identify which sos number you need pick ?

Comment: This actually worked, I was using something incorrectly on my end. Thank you so much!